# UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE But other files are getting uploaded

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I am facing a quite weird behavior in my server.

I can upload any files smaller than 1MB without problem, but those that are bigger return me an error UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE == 7.

The tmp/ folder has permissions since I can upload other files.

The config on my PHP.INI seems to be fine, I did upload files larger than 1MB using phpmyadmin before and it worked.

PHP.INI

- file_uploads  On
- post_max_size 200M
- max_execution_time    30
- memory_limit  128M
- max_file_uploads  20
- upload_max_filesize   200M
- upload_tmp_dir    /tmp

There's something I am missing? at my local machine works perfectly same config :S

I use ubuntu server 13.04 PHP 5.4.9 and Apache 2.2.22

Sure is the most stupid thing ever and I wasted 2 hours in this, I already have checked loads of docs at php.net but no luck. Any help is more than welcome.

Thanks!!!

UPDATE 10-01-2014: Still no luck I could not fix it.

Comment: the destination has writable permission ? It should be 775.

Comment: as said I can upload files smaller than 1mb no problem :S

Comment: Have faced same problem recently , very rare but hair pulling issue, thanks for adding it

Answer (score 22):

Thanks to all your answers I found the error.

The server is an Ubuntu installation done by OVH installer. What I was not aware is that they will create the partitions in such a poorly way:

- Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
- **overflow        1.0M  136K  888K  14% /tmp**
- /dev/md2        1.8T   13G  1.7T   1% /home

So what I did is modify in php.ini the upload_tmp_dir to another folder with space...

Terrible I've wasted so much time, I never thought was actually an space issue, since in the HD I have 2TB!

Once more thanks and hope this may work to someone else.

Comment: This was the solution for me too.  The disk on my AWS micro instance disk filled up.  I cleared out a bunch of junk, but I was still seeing the error.  I set upload_tmp_dir to /usr/tmp and everything started working again.  I still don't know where the original tmp directory is though.

Comment: Mine, like chema's, was defaulting to /tmp, which on my AWS instance was also defined as a measely 1M "overflow" partition (whatever that means). This appears to be an unfortunate effect of combining PHP's default location for `upload_tmp_dir` with AWS's bizarre /tmp partition. Changing the php.ini to point to a larger drive did the trick. Thanks for solving this.

Comment: Actually according to [this link](http://jarrodoverson.com/blog/overflow-filesystem-in-linux/), this strange /tmp partition is a result of running out of space on your regular partition and like hwrod's answer all you have to do is unmount it again.

Comment: I spent 3 days on it and your comment saved me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Delete or move all files from /tmp and unmount the device so it uses the normal partition for /tmp.

```
 mkdir /usr/tmp
 mv /tmp/* /usr/tmp
 sudo umount -l /tmp
 mv /usr/tmp/* /tmp
```

Comment: this looks like a nice solution, didnt try though.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably due to your `memory_limit` configuration. Try to replace with 256M. If it works you should review your code to minify memory usage.

If it is due to your permissions configuration you'll see with:

```
ls -la /yourUploadDirectory
```

You should see something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x 65 user group     4096 nov 13 09:47 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 user   group       4096 ago  7 18:09 ..
```

`group` of `.` directory (first line) should be `www-data`. If it's not do:

```
chown yourUser:www-data /yourUploadDirectory
```

Also `drwxr-xr-x` should be `drwxrwxr-x`. If it's not do:

```
chmod 0775 /yourUploadDirectory
```

Now you're done to upload.

Comment: Hello, thanks for prompt reply. I havent tried before the memory_limit I raised it to 512MB and still no luck. Permissions on upload folder are fine. I can upload other smaller files :s weird isn't?

Comment: @chema, is there any file size limitation at your host?? Could you try to use `file_put_contents()` to write a 1 MB txt file ???

Comment: @AllenChak I have a dedicated server. :S I guess I am missing something stupid. Funny thing just 2 weeks a go I managed to restore a mysql DB of more than 10MB from phpmyadmin and it worked. Also note that the PHP script finish correctly but returning the witting error, when obviously he can write :S desperate here. Thanks!

Comment: Also checkout your `open_basedir` php.ini option. It should be comment, or written the directories that Apache can access.

Comment: @ManoloSalsas open_basedir no value, but as I said before, apache can write there. I uploaded smaller files before with success. Just tried now and also worked :S but file bigger than 1 MB I get the message that he cant write...

Comment: Ok. Are you sure that you're changing the right file? Check: `find /etc/* -name php.ini` and `diff file1 file2` to know if there are differences between them.

Comment: I think so since the insfo I am getting it from phpinfo(); function and reflects my changes.

Comment: Uhm... Are you sure that you have enough free space in the hard disk? Try `df` command.

Comment: Still couldnt fix this. I am able to pay someone to do it for me. Anyone in the room?

Comment: It,s maybe obvious, but have you restated your server after your `php.ini` changes? `service apache2 restart`